# C# | DataGridView value are at the end not at the beginning

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

I am currently working on a little database tool.. The Problem is when I click on a button a new column is getting added to the DataGridView till this all is fine and working.. now the problem is when I insert the value the value is not getting inserted at the beginning of the DataGridView it's getting inserted at the end.

Example:

```
ID     NAME
1      John     
2      Jill
```

This is before the value is getting inserted.

After inserting it looks like this:

```
ID     NAME     ZIP
1      John
2      Jill
                123
                345
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
ID     NAME     ZIP
1      John     123
2      Jill     345
```

That's the code:

```
        dt.Columns.Add("ZIP");

        DataRow dr;

        foreach(string ZIP in Col1)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["ZIP"] = ZIP;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: You're creating and adding new rows, what would you expect?

Comment: you should update existing data and not insert new data. your code doesn't show the code where you trying to do it